# Block specific API request system-wide

Tags: windows-10, url, blocking, api

I'd like to block system-wide the request to the Graph API getting profile images from Graph that is using this url:

> ```
> https://tasks.office.com/COMPANY.onmicrosoft.com/GraphApiV1/GetUserPhotoAsync
> ```

I've tested it with uBlock Origin and it works with this rule:

> ```
> ||tasks.office.com/COMPANY.onmicrosoft.com/GraphApiV1/GetUserPhotoAsync?
> ```

The downside is that it works only in a single browser and I cannot block profile images in Teams or other applications.

So I thought I add this address to my ESET's Web & Email block list like shown here, but it doesn't work. The images still load. I've tried various patterns like these:

> ```
> https://tasks.office.com/COMPANY.onmicrosoft.com/GraphApiV1/GetUserPhotoAsync
> https://tasks.office.com/COMPANY.onmicrosoft.com/GraphApiV1/GetUserPhotoAsync?
> https://tasks.office.com/COMPANY.onmicrosoft.com/GraphApiV1/GetUserPhotoAsync?*
> *.office.com/COMPANY.onmicrosoft.com/GraphApiV1/GetUserPhotoAsync?*
> ```

What else can I try?

Comment: What is your router's model ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way this could be accomplished is by running a man-in-the-middle attack against the software you’re running. Otherwise, you cannot filter on specific request paths. On an abstract level, you need the following:

- A proxy that can do HTTPS interception (and possibly also the filtering you want)
- A Certificate Authority (CA) that…

  - your software must trust
  - the proxy will use to issue certificates for intercepted connections

Please note that is is ***security critical*** your CA private key remain secret. Otherwise, when someone gets this key, you truly are open to MITM attacks.

---

One popular web filtering proxy is [Provixy](https://www.privoxy.org/). According to its documentation, it can do HTTPS inspection. The [manual](https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html#HTTPS-INSPECTION-DIRECTIVES) describes the following relevant config options:

- `ca-directory`
- `ca-cert-file`
- `ca-key-file`
- `ca-password`
- `certificate-directory`
- `trusted-cas-file` (this is important)

Furthermore, the [`https-inspection` action](https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#HTTPS-INSPECTION) needs to be enabled for specific sites:

```
{+https-inspection}
tasks.office.com
```